# Why can't I use n = 5 inside rnorm function inside map2()?

Tags: r, data-analysis

My code is:

[image]

But as value I am getting null value. Why is that? If I put it like:
[image]

Then the code works. What is the reason? I thought I should mention my desired number of random number inside the rnorm function.

Comment: Could you please include your code as text (cut-and-paste into a code block) rather than in an image/screenshot format?

Answer (score 1):

`map2` takes *functions* as arguments. `rnorm` is a function, but `rnorm(5)` is *not* a function. It is a *call* to the function `rnorm` which evaluates to a numeric vector. `map2` needs a *function* that it will apply to your data. If you supply it with a numeric vector instead of a function, it will throw an error.

Using `map2` without `n = 5` would pass your `mu` list to the first argument of `rnorm`, which is `n`, and your `sd` list to the second argument, which is `mu`. Therefore, it is more conventional to write your `map2` call explicitly using a function that takes two arguments and returns the desired output:

```r
map2(.x = mu, .y = sd, .f = function(.x, .y) rnorm(n = 5, mu = .x, sd = .y))
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  -998.2274 -1000.0183  -999.1472  -999.7948 -1003.0080
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  -6.830560  -2.120511   1.184018 -11.713616   4.808483
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  993.9557  992.4712  984.4439  985.4611 1000.5633
```

As in other tidyverse functions, we can use the lamda notation, where `function(.x, .y)` can be replaced with a `~`, so one would typically write:

```r
map2(.x = mu, .y = sd, .f = ~ rnorm(n = 5, mu = .x, sd = .y))
```

That's not to say that your code is *wrong* - it will produce the correct result, but being explicit like this helps you understand what's going on.

Finally, just for absolute clarity, the name of the lists you put in has no connection to the arguments of the function they are passed to:

```r
apples  <- list(-1000, 0, 1000)
oranges <- list(1, 5, 10)

map2(.x = apples, .y = oranges, .f = ~ rnorm(n = 5, mu = .x, sd = .y))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] -1001.6189 -1000.1097  -999.5591  -998.6490 -1001.3186
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  1.8219230  1.1674992  5.9697763 -0.1395499 -1.7864943
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  988.5319  994.8258  996.3788 1023.5055 1024.4653
```

Comment: meta-comment: consider requesting that new posters include code, data etc. in a text format rather than as a screenshot, and waiting to answer until they do so ... ?

Comment: I don't always follow my own advice either. In this case OP is fairly new, asking questions fairly frequently, and using screenshots in most of them -- it's a matter of setting expectations I think. (I don't think it's a big deal though.) I called it a meta-comment because it's not a comment about your answer, but about best practices.

Comment: @BenBolker thanks - I didn't check the OP's history. The number of code-as-pictures questions on SO seems very high despite attempts by SE and all of us to dissuade OPs from the practice. For new users, I reckon only a change to the question-asking interface can reliably reduce it. For OPs who repeatedly post such questions, then I can see that not providing answers unless they are rectified is probably part of the solution. That's good advice.